# Cannot import WebClient from slack even after installation of slack and slackclient module?

Tags: python, api, importerror, slack, slack-api

**Have installed both of modules: slack and slackclient**
**slack==0.0.2
slackclient==2.6.1**

Doing this:

```
from slack import WebClient
```

Gives Error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient' from 'slack' (/home/sudip/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slack/**init**.py)

Comment: I just went to the folder and see that , the path of the webclient i was using inside the code was incorrect . Be sure to check the package str before importing

Answer (score 2):

I am going to go on a limb here and say that this is because of how the libraries were been changed in late '19.

#### Try this

1. For python, use this library --> https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient
2. `pip install slackclient`
3. `import slack` on top of your file and get your client value by `CLIENT = slack.WebClient(token='xxxxx')`